# Python script complete exit

Tags: python

I'm currently using quit() to end my program but the command line still persists after the execution has finished. How do I "kill" the program?

```
def ed():
    quit()

timer = threading.Timer(time, ed)
timer.start()
```

[image]

The pointer stays active and acts like the script is running.

Comment: exit from current situation? Try  sending ```SIGINT```  to process using ```Ctrl + C```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```
import os

def ed():
    os._exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard function of Python `exit()` which can print whatever before exiting and exit from program.

```
print("start") 
exit() # exiting from program
print("end")
```

> start

### or

```
print("start") 
exit("exiting") # exiting with output
print("end")
```

> start
>
> exiting